# ASPX View MVC3 WebGrid format column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, view, webgrid

```
<%{
     WebGrid studentGrid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: StudentController.PageSize);
     studentGrid.Bind(Model.Students, autoSortAndPage: false, rowCount: Model.RowCount);
     studentGrid.PageIndex = Model.CurrentPage;
}%>

<%=studentGrid.GetHtml(columns: new WebGridColumn[]{
    studentGrid.Column("StudentId", "Id"),
    studentGrid.Column("Name", "Name"),
 })%>
```

Unfortunatly i am forced to use aspx view in my MVC3 project.

I want to have a column that shows a text "select" or "remove" based on some condition of the list item that is bound to the grid.

How is the sysntax to do that

I have to get render html like

```
<span class="1" id=item.id>Select<span>
```

and the html shown will be just **Select**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do it with `format` you just need to handcraft the HTML in C#:

```
<%

    var list = new[]
                    {
                        new { StudentId = 1, Name = "Name1", Cond = true },
                        new { StudentId = 2, Name = "Name3", Cond = false },
                        new { StudentId = 2, Name = "Name3", Cond = true },
                    };
    WebGrid studentGrid = new WebGrid();
    studentGrid.Bind(list, autoSortAndPage: false, rowCount: 3); 

%>
<%= studentGrid.GetHtml(columns: 
    new WebGridColumn[]
        {
            studentGrid.Column("StudentId", "Id"),
            studentGrid.Column("Name", "Name"),
            studentGrid.Column(header: "Action",  
                format: item =>
                {
                    string span = "<span class=\"1\" id=\"{0}\">{1}<span>";
                    string action = item.Cond ? "Select" : "Remove";
                    return Html.Raw(string.Format(span, item.StudentId, action));
                })
        })
%>
```

Using the aspx template systax (eg. `<% %>`) inside a lambda is supported in general (see this [Telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/templatesserverside)) but because the `WebGrid` working diffidently than Telrik it's not working.

It seems the way is `WebGrid` built only supports razor templates inside the `format` argument...