# The Syntax for ASPX ASP MVC @model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

@model Webgrid.Models.Employee

What is the syntax of the above code in ASPX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strongly typed views need to derive from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<T>` where `T` is your model type:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Webgrid.Models.Employee>" %>
```

Or if you are having an `ascx` page then from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<T>`

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"        
            Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Webgrid.Models.Employee>" %>
```

Comment: i have used WebGrid using ASPX please check whether the code is right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351486/fetch-all-the-value-from-database-to-webgrid-of-asp-mvc-aspx

Comment: why is razor simple to use and ASPX very difficult

Comment: Razor was designed for easy use for MVC. ASPX was the view language and it is designed for ASP.NET WebForms. And ASP.NET MVC just supports both. You can use both of them in the same project side by side.

Comment: i have referred your method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801743/aspx-view-mvc3-webgrid-format-column

Comment: I have used your method i am getting only the last value in webgrid for the code used in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351486/fetch-all-the-value-from-database-to-webgrid-of-asp-mvc-aspx?lq=1

Comment: @Anish what do you mean on multiple models? If a list/collection of them then you can write: `<%@ Page Language="C#"     Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Webgrid.Models.Employee>>" %>` otherwise each view can have only one type of model which can be accessed with the `Model` property in the view.